# How to finetune a Huggingface Detr Model with a custom trained Backbone (weights not on [timm](https://timm.fast.ai/))?

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to finetune the [Detection Transformer model](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/detr#transformers.DetrForObjectDetection) using this [awesome tutorial](https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/tree/master/DETR). But I am unable to set a custom `backbone` (something other than the pretrained models and weights found on `timm`) in the DetrConfig

This works:

```
config = DetrConfig.from_pretrained(pt_model_path,
                                    id2label=id2label,
                                    label2id=label2id,
                                    num_queries=num_queries,
                                    backbone='resnet50')
model = DetrForObjectDetection.from_pretrained(
        pt_model_path, config=config, ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)
```

But this does not:

```
config = DetrConfig.from_pretrained(pt_model_path,
                                    id2label=id2label,
                                    label2id=label2id,
                                    num_queries=num_queries,
                                    backbone='./my_custom_trained/cnn/backbone.pth')
model = DetrForObjectDetection.from_pretrained(
        pt_model_path, config=config, ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)
```

Comment: As [Huggingface documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/detr#transformers.DetrConfig.backbone) says you can only specify a model from the [timm](https://rwightman.github.io/pytorch-image-models/#load-a-pretrained-model) library. Looks like timm is a collection of pre-trained models.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware, I wonder if I can load custom weights onto the Timm model and use this model as the backbone.